# Why did KDE 4.11 from ppa remove kwin-style-qtcurve?

Tags: ppa, kde4

When installing KDE 4.11 from backports ppa, I noticed it removed kwin-style-qtcurve. After the update(all went fine), I tried to install it and it wanted to remove kwin. Why?

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsb_release -a; echo; ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`, `apt-cache policy kwin kwin-style-qtcurve`, `apt-get -s install kwin-style-qtcurve`, and `apt-get -s install kwin-style-qtcurve kwin` to your question? (None of those commands needs to be run with `sudo`; they don't install or remove any software, but are purely diagnostic.)

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1213066

> Philip Muškovac (yofel) wrote 4 hours ago:  qtcurve fix uploaded to
>   backport ppa.